# How can I make an MSI file that runs all EXEs in its own directory?

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

Currently, our customer uses a Windows .bat file in order to batch-install a series of installers (currently .exe files produced using Inno Setup, although there are plans in the future to replace them with .msi installers) found in a directory.

However, they have requested that this be replaced with an .msi file -- it sounds crazy to me (as it doesn't actually INSTALL anything, merely search for external files already on the target machine and then run them) -- but presumably it is in order to take advantage of Windows Installers' logging functionality, as well as to prevent unauthorized tampering with the installation process.

Most of the stuff I've found on Windows Installer custom actions seems to refer to running programs installed by the MSI, not programs that were already on the target machine before the installer was run.  What do I need to do to run already-existing files (in the same directory as the MSI itself) as part of an MSI's processing?

I'll accept solutions using either Visual Studio or WiX.

Comment: does the solution have to be a .msi? Can it not be a .exe? Also, you say that the files you wish to run are installers themselves, but then say that they are 'programs that were already on the target machine'. Can you clear that up? You can use WiX to create a bootstrapper which will do what you want, it's called WiX Burn.

Comment: I thought it ought to be an .exe too, but the customer requested .msi.

I meant that the installers themselves were already on the target machine -- incidentally I think my first stab at solving this problem will be to make the MSI run JScript code which searches the current directory for the installers.

Comment: What your customers are actually asking for is to get rid of your EXE installers and refactor using MSI. Not to create a fake "Trojan" MSI installer that just encapsulates your current EXE installers. I can say this because I'm the deployment architect for a Fortune 35 company and I have this conversation with vendors on a regular basis.

Comment: Chris's answer is the only explanation that makes sense about what the customer wants. All those setups need converting to one (or more) MSI setups for the customer. Their request cannot possibly mean "use an MSI to run the exes instead of a bat file".